# 1 second of delay of css on html page load?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to make some html and css pages. Every time when I load a page. It always give me about half a second flash of the html page without the css style. Anyone know why that happens and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Solved: thanks guys, I just place my jquery at the bottom and it fix the problem.

Comment: What browser? Most of them offer some timing tools to show what happens.

Comment: That can happen, because of the css files, not loading  fast enough. Use jquery in the footer and keep the main stylesheet above any other stylesheets

Comment: Can u please post some code from the html page, where is the css referenced in the html doc? Also how large is the css file?

Comment: Please post the header section of ur html page as well

Comment: Could it be you are seeing a [FOUC](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/index.php?fix=LINK)?

Comment: That's exactly what I thought about the css files are not loading as fast as the html. And I linked the css file at the top. but it doesn't help.

Comment: You will have to post enough html that reproduces the problem, or we won't be able to help you...

Comment: @tipsywacky rather than "Beat around the bush" ,,,, why not share code .. if you really want us to help you out ..

Comment: oh wait, i did have jquery at the header.

Comment: file is too long, i used it in jinja template and it consist of 2 files.

Comment: @tipsywacky did it got resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest the following :-

1. Remove any jquery from header and place it to the bottom of the page .
2. Remove excess white space from your coding.
3. Reduce the size of your images files.
4. Try to combine many scripts into one if possible.
5. Remove any unnecessary elements .
6. Combine all style sheets into one - lesser files , lesser response time and faster loading time.
7. Optimize your background image or any image you are using on the page for faster loading.
8. In the end use Gzip to minify JS , CSS and HTML . Never use it on images,videos,pdf's - wont do any additional compression ,but might increase the size .

Answer (score 8):

for others who have the same problem,
in my situation the delay was from `autofocus=""` attribute in the text input, so I removed that and the problem solved!

hope this helps

Comment: Who would have thought of this? Your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just one LINK element or SCRIPT element inside a document's HEAD element will prevent a flash of unstyled content.

Answer (score 2):

Put a script tag with 0 inside the head

```html
<head>
    <!-- Other head stuff ... -->
    <script>0</script>
</head>
```