# Whole CSS appearing, disappearing, and then re-appearing again on page load

Tags: html, css, page-refresh, pageload

I'm having a weird issue with my company's website. There is a blink when you load, with no CSS applied. I thought it just meant the CSS was delayed, but looking at the loading timeline:

[image: Timeline of page load]

It seems the CSS is applied, then after 400ms *it stops being applied* and then after ~500ms it is applied again.

I'm unable to see what could cause this kind of issue.

#### How to replicate:

Go to [this site](https://www.milleporte.com/sale/all). Press Enter on the address bar (for some reason the problem doesn't appear when simply refreshing).

The problem appears only when cache is *not* disabled.

Replicated on Chrome and Firefox, doesn't seem to appear on Safari.

Doesn't appear when running as a localhost

Doesn't seem to be affected by presence/absence of adblockers

Comment: It does happen on refresh too

Comment: do you use custom fonts? if you disable them, will you still have that problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919309/4896467

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix, still haven't found the reason.

#### The fix:

Move the CSS before the JS in the header. [This shouldn't have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272730/1032982), but apparently it does in this situation.

#### The reason:

As far as I can tell, the problematic flow is the following:

1 - The browser gets the CSS from the cache and applies it

2 - The browser *for some reason* realizes it should use the header's CSS instead, and *removes* the cache CSS

3 - The scripts (mainly google analytics) delay the CSS loading enough that we can see a bit of no css website

Still don't understand point 2 at all, but the fix works. And I'm paid to make it work, not to understand it, so question closed.