# Page blink when using tailwindcss

Tags: webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, tailwind-css

I am trying to use tailwindcss on a 5.2 ruby on rails application with webpack. Everything is set up and works well. Except a tiny problem that prevent me from putting the app on production.

When pages are loaded, I first see the page without css during less than half a second and then the css is applied and everything goes back to normal.

Here are some captures of the issue:
[Planning page loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh2cP.gif)
[Sign in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox9i6.gif)

NB: The app is light (only 3 pages more or less, nothing fancy with big video/img...)

I don't understand why. Do you have any idea to solve the issue?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does the page source look like in the browser? Maybe it's a loading issue, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919236/1-second-of-delay-of-css-on-html-page-load)?

Comment: I placed the tags stylesheet_pack_tag and even javascript_pack_tag on top of head. Still the same. I removed all the image from the app --> still the same. I gathered all the css files into one --> still the same. Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: It would probably help if  you post the page source, as it appears in the browser, in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries, I notice that the blink appears only in development. When the assets are compiled in production, the blinks disappear.

Thanks for your efforts.