# SVG oversized on load until CSS kicks in

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG inside a fixed-size div (`width: 350px; height: 400px;`) and everything is fine once the page loads, but during the loading, the SVG is oversized and mangled up until CSS kicks in:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code, HTML first:

```
<div class="dashboard-tasks-completed">
  <figure>
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#19222a" stroke-width="5"></circle>
      <circle id="active" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#206996" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="66.66666666666666 33.33333333333333" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
      <circle id="completed" class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#B8E1FA" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="33.33333333333333 66.66666666666666" stroke-dashoffset="58.33333333333334"></circle>
      <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">3</text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label"> Tasks </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <figcaption class="figure-key">
      <ul class="figure-key-list" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
        <li>
          <span class="shape-circle shape-blue"></span>2 Active (66.67%)
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="shape-circle shape-lightblue"></span>1 Completed (33.33%)
        </li>
      </ul>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dashboard-tasks-completed {
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
}

.chart-text {
    font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;
    fill: #000;
    transform: translateY(0.25em);
}

.chart-number {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    line-height: 1;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}

.chart-label {
    font-size: 0.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateY(0.7em);
}

.figure-key-list {
    list-style: none;
}

.figure-key-list li {
    margin: 0 0 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.shape-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.shape-blue { background-color: #206996; }

.shape-lightblue { background-color: #B8E1FA }
```

I have created a minimal example, unfortunately it is not reproducible in neither JSFiddle or Codepen, but here is the [demo](https://codepen.io/lbastos/pen/KKKXOxR) in any case.

How can I overcome the issue?

Comment: Dooes your CSS get loaded before any content or after? AKA is it in your `<head>` or at the end of your `<body>`?

Comment: @somethinghere CSS is in my `<head>`.

Comment: Investigate these steps: [Delayed CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919309/11700321) - particularly the part about importing scripts at the bottom of the page (if possible)

Comment: @EGC: I don't have jQuery loading on that page, nor any other JS. The only CSS file is the file I pasted here. Those suggestions don't work for me.

Comment: This is called [Flash Of Unstyled SVG](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-style-inheritance-and-fousvg/#the-how). Read the article by Sara Soueidan

Comment: @enxaneta I have tried to set exact size of the SVG, however while the being oversized issue goes away, the text inside the donut still remains mangled up.

Comment: Please try `<svg width="270" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">`

Comment: @enxaneta as I said, I have tried to do that. The SVG would be no longer oversized on load, but the text would remain all mangled up.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you are letting the SVG fill the page until the CSS loads and it becomes the correct size.

- If you know your SVG is going to be `width: 350px; height: 400px;`, then you could set those dimensions on the SVG instead.

  ```
  <svg width="350px" height="400px" ...>
  ```

  Then put it back to what you want in the CSS.

  ```
  .dashboard-tasks-completed svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Or you could inline some basic styling in your document, that would set up some important sizes until the rest of the SVG loads.

  ```
  <head>
    <style>
      .dashboard-tasks-completed {
        width: 350px;
        height: 400px;
      }
      .chart-text {
        font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;
        fill: #000;
        transform: translateY(0.25em);
      }
    </style>
    ...
  ```
- And if your font size never changes, then why not just set those attributes on your `<text>` element instead of using CSS?

  ```
  <g class="chart-text" style="font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif; fill: #000; transform: translateY(0.25em);">
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to hide the `div` (or other elements within) initially and then reveal it after the page finishes loading.

For example, modify your `div` thusly:

```
<div id="showme" class="dashboard-tasks-completed" style="display:none;">
```

And then add the following javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById("showme").style.display = "block";
};
```

The inline CSS `display:none;` lets the browser know not to display it, even before external CSS is loaded. Once everything is loaded, your `onload` event will fire, and the javascript above will display the previously-hidden elements.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen workarounds like this before. If I don't find something more systematic, I'll have to use this workaround. Thanks.

Comment: You could also set all the css in-line on the individual elements, or embed your css in a script tag instead of an external file. Or you could pre-load your svg in a variable with js and append it to the DOM after page load.

Comment: You might actually get away with just setting the width and height on the div.

Comment: I have already set the width and height on the div. I have also tried to set exact size of the SVG, however while the oversizing issue would go away, it still remains mangled up.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately until the browser gets instructions on how to size everything, that's going to be the case. This is why it isn't a workaround but actually a common method to allow assets on a page to load before displaying elements.

Answer (score 0):

> The viewBox attribute defines the position and dimension, in user space, of an SVG viewport.
>
> The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers min-x, min-y, width and height, separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which is mapped to the bounds of the viewport established for the associated SVG element (not the browser viewport).

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox).

---

The viewbox property defines the region of an svg element which should be zoomed in on to fit inside it's container. However, the element will keep it's aspect ratio and not stretch to fit inside the container.

---

So in your case, this means that the svg element will fill all it's parents space while maintaining it's aspect ratio, until css arrives and tells it to size it self inside a 350px by 400px space.