# A small delay on my page when loading CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am having some "issues" when loading my page, it might take a small second before the css is loaded, so at first I see the "not styled" page, and after a small second it is normal.

My host is 000webhost, but maybe that doesn't matter.

Any tips?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919236/1-second-of-delay-of-css-on-html-page-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919236/1-second-of-delay-of-css-on-html-page-load)

Comment: @RobMoll `Just one LINK element or SCRIPT element inside a document's HEAD element will prevent a flash of unstyled content.` What does that mean? If I have link or script inside `<head>`, I should move it to for example the bottom of my page?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read this article from Google Developer
[Resource Prioritization – Getting the Browser to Help You](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization)

In short use

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="script-file.js">
```

For preloading javascript

```
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="styles-file.css">
```

For preloading CSS

Another advice would be to try and optimize your website and using resources only when required.

Also nothing to do with your hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is to move javascript to the bottom of the page and to defer the loading of the CSS as follows:

Wrap the content in a div that has display none and place that basic style inline in the head. Then in your CSS file have `.wrap{display:block;}`.

Then at the bottom defer the loading of the stylesheet until it has been loaded.

What is happening here is the page content is hidden by default (with the .wrap{display:none}`. Then when the CSS file is fully loaded, the` .wrap{display:block}` overrides the display none and the page is displayed all at once.

```
<html>
<head><style>.wrap{display:none;}</style></head>
<body>
        <div class="wrap">
           website content
        </div>





    <noscript id="deferred-styles">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        </noscript>
        <script>
          var loadDeferredStyles = function() {
            var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
            var replacement = document.createElement("div");
            replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
            document.body.appendChild(replacement)
            addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
          };
          var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
              webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
          if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
          else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```