# css styles get applied with 1s delay (styled-components?)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components, fouc

I am currently building my first [website/documentation](https://agile-ts.org) with React and help of docusaurus.
But as soon as I reload the site, for about 0.5 - 1s the css styles aren't applied properly (see img below).

After I have got a hint I found out that this phenomenon is called FOUC 'Flash of unstyled Content'.

In my case it occurs only in production. See video below
https://youtu.be/Zh2-1gtKOtI

It could have something to do with the [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) because the 'navbar' is the only part which has no styled components. And the navbar looks fine to me.

Codebase:
https://github.com/agile-ts/documentation

[image]

Thank you ^^

Comment: There isn't much to go with here to be able to help you, a picture doesn't say anything, Such problems requires a lot of testing and you didn't provide any code.

Comment: is it [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) maybe ? if it is, maybe this will help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919236/1-second-of-delay-of-css-on-html-page-load)

Comment: This thread might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919236/1-second-of-delay-of-css-on-html-page-load

Comment: yeah I took a look into the resources you suggested.. but after some testing I found out that it has 100% something to do with the styled-components. (See video below)
https://youtu.be/MhMFD8zcrb0

Answer (score 0):

ok it has something to do with docusaurus..
https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/3236

Comment: any solution for this?